# Why does objects get deleted after being inserted into set?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have set up this example:

```
class UsefulClass {
public: 
        int id;
        const bool operator< (const UsefulClass &other) const {
                return this->id > other.id;
        }
        UsefulClass(int _id): id(_id) {
                std::cout << "constructing " << id << std::endl;
        }
        ~UsefulClass() {
                std::cout << "destructing " << id << std::endl;
        }
};
std::set<UsefulClass> set;
void create() {
        UsefulClass object_1(1);
        UsefulClass object_2(2);
        set.insert(object_1);
        set.insert(std::move(object_2));

        std::cout << "create end" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
        create();
        std::cout << "main end" << std::endl;
}
```

I am expecting that the objects get destructed once when `set` gets deleted at the end of the program. But the objects get deleted twice:

```
constructing 1
constructing 2
create end
destructing 2
destructing 1
main end
destructing 1
destructing 2
```

Why is `set.insert` creating a copy here?

Comment: Local objects `object_1` and `object_2` get destroyed at the end of `create()`. Were you not expecting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects in the `set` are different from the objects local to `create()`.  The ones in the `set` are constructed using a copy constructor and move constructor, not the constructor `UsefulClass(int)`, so you don't see their construction.  The local objects get destroyed when the function `create()` returns, and then the objects in the `set` get destroyed at global cleanup after `main` ends.

Answer (score 2):

object_1 and object_2 are created on stack and will be destroyed once the create() function ends. They need to be copied in the memory managed by set's allocator.

If you redefine the copy constructor, to trace its execution, you'll notice it is called at both inserts.

Answer (score 1):

[Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) applies to your case, if you print from dtor and want meaningful trace you should instrument copy (and maybe move) ctor also.

If you do that output will make sense and things should be properly paired.

Answer (score 0):

Because your objects get copied on insertion into the set. Hence, when the `create()` function returns, the two local objects are destroyed. After `main` ends, the two copies that are in the set are destroyed, leading to the second pair of messages.

Comment: That is what Adam S says. He wants to know why copy is created?

Comment: Because C++ objects don't work the same way as Java objects (by default).

Comment: @dbasic: The question was why the objects are delete twice, which they aren't. The are deleted once and a pair of copies is delete lateron.

Comment: @arne: I was referring last line: Why is set.insert creating a copy here?

Comment: @dbasic Oh snap. I overlooked that one.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate whatever everybody has said before me, just create this simple example (it uses a new copy constructor for the set to use and uses a global variable to generate different `id`s each time a constructor is executed ---it's been tested, so you can put it in a file and compile):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class UsefulClass {
    static int instance;
public:
    int id;
    int i;

    const bool operator<(const UsefulClass &other) const {
        return id < other.id;
    }

    UsefulClass(int i){
        id = instance++;
        this->i = i;
        cout    << "constructing "
            << id
            << ":"
            << this->i
            << endl;
    }

    UsefulClass(const UsefulClass& other) {
        id = instance++;
        i = other.i;
        cout    << "constructing "
            << id
            << ":"
            << i
            << endl;
    }

        ~UsefulClass(){
        cout    << "destructing "
            << id
            << ":"
            << i
            << endl;
    }
};

int UsefulClass::instance = 0;

std::set<UsefulClass> myset;

void create() {
        UsefulClass object_1(1);
        UsefulClass object_2(2);
        myset.insert(object_1);
    /* please, explain what you mean with std::move, or which move
     * have you used for the next statement.  All i have is
     * std::move(... ) for strings, but you have not defined
     * string UsefulClass::operator string();
     */
        myset.insert(/*std::move*/(object_2));

        cout    << "create end"
        << endl;
}

int main() {
        create();
        cout    << "main end"
        << std::endl;
}
```

so you'll get a different instance id whenever you create a UsefulClass object and you'll see that when inserting into the set they are being copied as new instances.  You'll see when each object is being created and when they are being deleted.

```
$ pru
constructing 0:1
constructing 1:2
constructing 2:1
constructing 3:2
create end
destructing 1:2
destructing 0:1
main end
destructing 2:1
destructing 3:2
```